# using 'not' and 'or' together in Python

Tags: python, python-2.5

In Python 2.5, I used the code:

```
    yn=raw_input('''This program is for solving linear and quadratic equations.
    Is this what you want to do?
    ''')
    if not 'y' in yn or 'Y' in yn:
        print 'Program now quitting.'
```

to display `Program now quitting` when the program closed, which was supposed to happen when yn did not contain 'y' or 'Y', but it was also displayed when yn did contain 'Y', before the rest of the program started.  I think that the bug was caused by the use of 'or' and 'not' together, since it didn't change when I changed `if not 'y' in yn or 'Y' in yn:` to `if not 'y' in yn or not 'Y' in yn:`, but disappeared when I changed it to

```
    if not 'y' in yn:
        if not 'Y' in yn:
```

Is this right? What, if anything, could I do to solve the problem and keep this part in the same line?

Comment: Maybe if you add parenthesis you can get it right. The way it's written is ambiguous. The interpreter might have to decide between !(A || B) or (!A) || B.

Comment: `if not yn.lower() == 'y'` might be easier.

Comment: When in doubt look up ["Operator precedence"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and add parentheses in order of precedence: `in` then `not` then `or` results in `if ((not ('y' in yn)) or ('Y' in yn)):`. You can also write `if 'y' not in yn and 'Y' not in yn`

Comment: *The interpreter might have to decide between !(A || B) or (!A) || B.* That is wrong to say this, because there is [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in python, and thus the `not operator` has higher precedence than the `or operator`, so `not 'y' in yn or 'Y' in yn` is always interpreted as `(not 'y' in yn) or ('Y' in yn)`.

Answer (score 6):

`if not ('y' in yn or 'Y' in yn):` should work.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `yn` is the inputted string

Comment: Oh, in that case what's wrong with `if yn[0].upper() == 'Y':`

Comment: I assumed the `in` statement was to catch things like ` y`

Answer (score 2):

smitec's is right, but

```
if not 'y' in yn.lower():
```

might be easier.

Comment: I think that's the best answer because it is following the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):`Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.`

Comment: If you convert `yn` to lower-case, it's even simpler to use string comparison: `if yn.lower() != 'y':`

Comment: It solves the current problem, but does not answer the question about `not` and `or`.  Nevertheless, I would suggest to write it like this, of course ;-)

Comment: it actually answers the question: *What, if anything, could I do to solve the problem and keep this part in the same line?* by simplifying it!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (not 'y' in yn) or (not 'Y' in yn):
    print 'Program Now Quitting.'
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt use braces :)

depending on what you want to achieve it can be:

```
if (not 'y' in yn) or ('Y' in yn):
```

or:

```
if not ('y' in yn or 'Y' in yn):
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider writing it more readable as

```
if 'y' not in yn and 'Y' not in yn:
  pass  # ...
```

The `not in` operator does not suffer from the problems you've just run into.

Concerning your direct question:  The `not` operator binds with a high priority, so

```
not x or y
```

is interpreted as

```
(not x) or y
```

You have to set parentheses if you want to override this:

```
not (x or y)
```

or transpose the term:

```
not x and not y
```